# JQuery - Two textboxes excute the same codes

Tags: jquery

This should be a simple question, but I am new to JQuery.

The code below will execute when a textbox with ID="CompanyName" entered. I have another textbox with ID="City".  How can I put and OR statement, saying that "Either CompanyName or City boxes enter, process the same code below.

Thanks,

```
   $('#CompanyName').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            //alert("Found");
            e.preventDefault();
            // Some code here.....
        }
    });
```

Comment: really? -> `$('#CompanyName, #City').on('keypress', ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try giving them a common class, and selecting that instead, eg

```
$('.class-name').on('keypress', function(e) {
```

Comment: Thank you, must simpler method.

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify multiple selectors, separated by ","

> $('#CompanyName, #City').on('keypre..

This should fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#CompanyName, #City").change(function() {
  //alert ("Found);
  .........
  execute code
  .........
)};
```